# remove first row from csv file and create table according to it

Tags: php, mysql, csv, fastercsv

Hi I am trying to be at point.

I am trying to upload **CSV** into **mysql** atonce by using php in windows. so I am using the query

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/Data/mysql/transaction_upload.csv'
INTO TABLE transaction_upload
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

it load my whole csv into the table.

The problem is:

1. The condition is that the table "transaction_upload" should be already exist.
2. It upload first row of csv too which contain header.

I want that first row will removed from CSV i.e. the header should not be have entry in DB and the table created automatically having name as CSV_file_name and columns as CSV first row's columns.

Please do not answer as read first line of CSV in php and create table because the problem of removing first row from is still there.

Comment: Does it have something to do with php?

Comment: @code breaker... did you get it..! Iam looking for something similar.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `IGNORE 1 LINES` to the end of your `LOAD DATA` command.

As the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) says:

> The **`IGNORE`*`number`*`LINES`** option can be used to ignore lines at the start of the file. For example, you can use **`IGNORE 1 LINES`** to skip over an initial header line containing column names:
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test IGNORE 1 LINES;
> ```

If the table does not already exist, MySQL will raise an error.

Comment: thankx it works work the table should be already exist, can u tell me the way to create table according to the first row but not as read columns of csv in php and create table.

Comment: @CodeBreaker: The problem is that CSV doesn't contain sufficient information (such as column data types) for MySQL to correctly create the table - you need to provide additional information with a [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html) command; if using another language (like PHP) for this, there are plenty of tools that can assist you (like PHP's [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function).  (You *could* go via MySQL's (type-unsafe) [CSV storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/csv-storage-engine.html), but I don't recommend it).